# Python encryption and decryption function is giving me a Unicode error

Tags: python, encryption, unicode

Here are some encryption and decryption functions that I created for a python key management library I am writing.

```
def generate_RSA():
    bits = 2048
    new_key = RSA.generate(bits)
    public_key = new_key.publickey()
    private_key = new_key
    return private_key, public_key

def encrypt_data(in_fd, chunk_size, pub_key):
    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pub_key)
    A = list()
    with open(in_fd, 'rb') as in_file:
         while True:
               chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
               if len(chunk) == 0:
                  break
               elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
               encrypted_file = encryptor.encrypt(chunk) 
    return encrypted_file

def decrypt_data(in_fd, chunk_size, priv_key):
    decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(priv_key)
    with open(in_fd, 'rb') as in_file:
         while True:
               chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
               if len(chunk) == 0:
                  break
               decrypted_file = decryptor.decrypt(eval(str(chunk)))
    return decrypted_file
```

I wanted to be able to insert the encrypt_data and decrypt_data into each other as the first arguments if need be. However I am running into a problem.

```
 priv_key, pub_key = generate_RSA()
 print(decrypt_data(encrypt_data('C:\\Users\cowbo\OneDrive\Documents\EWC\Haiku.txt', 8192, pub_key), 8192, priv_key))
```

Whenever I try to run the last line of code, I get the following traceback...

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\cowbo\source\repos\Python Practice\PythonPractice\FileCounter.py", line 57, in <module>
       print(decrypt_data(encrypt_data('C:\\Users\cowbo\OneDrive\Documents\EWC\Haiku.txt', 8192, pub_key), 8192, priv_key))
    File "C:\Users\cowbo\source\repos\Python Practice\Python Practice\FileCounter.py", line 31, in decrypt_data
       with open(in_fd, 'rb') as in_file:
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I have looked at other post on here concerning this same issue and I seem to encrypting and decrypting correctly so Im not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Ah, and that’s exactly it; I bet you are passing the encrypted data as a filename to the decrypt function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *face palm* yup thats it. So if thats the problem how do I pass the encrypted data into the decryp_data function without having to create a new file and writing the encrypted data into that file?

Comment: And apologies for the run-around with the traceback and stale bytecode. I forgot that the `open(filename, ...)` call could trigger a decoding error on Windows. All other such decoding errors would require that you were already reading from the open file object, and had it opened in text mode. But `rb` is binary mode, and it was the file opening itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the result from `encrypt_data()` directly to `decrypt_data()`:

```
print(decrypt_data(encrypt_data(...))
```

`encrypt_data()` returns the *encrypted data*, not a filename:

```
       encrypted_file = encryptor.encrypt(chunk) 
return encrypted_file
```

(You are only producing the last chunk of encrypted data there, not all of it, but that’s not the cause of this error).

`decrypt_data()` doesn’t accept encrypted data however. It accepts a *filename*:

```
def decrypt_data(in_fd, chunk_size, priv_key):
    # ...
    with open(in_fd, 'rb') as in_file:
```

What threw me at first was that *on anything but Windows* that’ll give you a “file not found” error, but on Windows, a binary value for a file path will first be decoded as UTF-8, and that fails for the encrypted data.

To fix this, you have three options:

1. Have the encryption function open a new file, write the encrypted data to that file and return the filename instead of the encrypted data. Then you at least pass on the correct information to the decryption function.
2. Create the file for the encrypted data the encrypted data the encryption function returns at the point where you call the encryption function. Don’t pass the result directly to the decryption function, pass the filename.
3. Change the decryption function to accept the data directly and not read it from a file.

As a side note, in the decryption function you use:

```
decryptor.decrypt(eval(str(chunk)))
```

That's... a rather odd way of passing `chunk` directly to the decryption function. This is enough:

```
decryptor.decrypt(chunk)
```

`chunk` is a `bytes` object, `str(bytesvalue)` gives you `"b'...'"` (where `b'` at the start and `'` at the end are now part of the string) and `eval()` gives you the original `bytesvalue` again. Just pass the original in, no need to waste cycles there.

Comment: Option 1 is actually what I was doing before but I thought that maybe I would be able to do this without having to make a new file. I appreciate the help!!